# Two routers connected to a switch= same IP host address?

Tags: router

I have two routers, named Router0 and Router1, that are connect to a switch on ports `FA0/1` and `FA0/2`, respectively. Now lets say this network has an address of `201.201.201.0/24`.

Would the IP host address of both router interfaces that connect to this switch be the same, e.g. `.1` for Router0 `FA0/0`, and `.1` for Router1 `FA0/0`, or would the Router1 interface be `.2`?

I know in the real world, if you're connecting countries, you would not use this setup as its not ideal.

[image: network with cisco packet tracer]

Comment: The interfaces must have differnt IPs.

Comment: ah so for router0 it would be .1 ip host address and router1 it would be .2 correct?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Devices on the same IP network must have different addresses. Your routers' `f0/0` interfaces will be in the same network, so they will need to have different addresses. The addresses can be any of the usable network addresses, e.g. `201.201.201.1` to `201.201.201.254`.